# Which one is the correct way to say "what I like most is to sing"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, word-order

Which is the correct way to say "what I like most is to sing"? Someone said no. 3. If it is, why we have to use 的 particle?

1. 我最喜欢是唱歌
2. 我最喜欢唱歌
3. 我最喜欢的是唱歌

Answer (score 3):

我最喜欢的是唱歌 is the only answer that comes close to the original sentence -  "what I like most (possessive phrase) is to sing", which can be translated as "什麼是**我最喜欢的** - 是唱歌". Note the leading part is a possessive phrase, and after eliminating the first three words, the remaining sentence is - 我最喜欢**的**(possessive particle)是唱歌.

Comment on the other sentences:

- 我最喜欢是唱歌 is grammatically incorrect, as here, both 喜欢(like) and 是(is) are verbs that shouldn't stay next to each other.
- 我最喜欢唱歌 = I like singing the most. This is a correct sentence but with a style different than the original.

Answer (score 2):

They are all correct

1. 我最喜欢唱歌 = I really like to sing(v)
2. 我最喜欢是唱歌 = what I like the most is singing(n) - (among the activities I do)
3. 我最喜欢的是唱歌 = what I like the most is singing(n) - (among the activities I do)

- The difference between 2 and 3 is 的 is omitted in #2
- 的 in 我最喜欢的是唱歌 acts as a pronoun for 'activity'
- 的 in 我最喜欢的歌 is an adjective marker

More example:

我最喜欢的酒吧 = the bar that I like the most

我最喜欢的是酒吧 = 我最喜欢的(地方)是酒吧 = (Place) I like the most is a bar

我最喜欢的約翰 = John whom I like the most

我最喜欢的是約翰 = 我最喜欢的(人)是約翰 = (The person) I like the most is John

Comment: Thank you very much Tang Ho, so as far as I understand, the no. 2 and 3 (in your list) are the same meanning?  no difference due lack of 的?

Comment: 我最喜欢是酒吧 (I like the most is a bar) = 我最喜欢(的)是酒吧 = (the place) I like the most is a bar

Answer (score 1):

What I like most is singing. (What a pity I can't sing!)
唱歌是我最喜欢的活动。